# Using Pubsub to implement groups like Whatsapp in XMPP

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe

We're trying to use Pubsub to implement groups like those in Whatsapp, without the user having to go into the room, getting notifications while offline, etc..

So far, things have been working great. We can create a node, set publish to all, send, all the basic things needed in a room.

The problem is, when a user publishes to a node, no user information is sent.

Is there any way to do that? We thought of perhaps creating a normal XMPP message, and then sending it in the payload, but that'd require parsing it back from the payload. Is there any alternative solution? Or does that seem like the most viable one?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to do ? "When user publishes to a node, no user information is sent" What does it mean ? What user information do you expect ?

Comment: The same that is sent in a message. His JID, his nickname, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put all the data you need in the payload of the pubsub publish if you want to receive them.

Yes, it means it has drawback. For example, user could use a different need for each message. The Multi User chat rule are not enforced / control by pubsub, as this is designed for a different purpose.

Note, that I explained in a video that we now have everything to build that type of service on top of MUC: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWhm7C5DSgg

Comment: I was thinking of just switching to MUC as well. Would the video help me if I'm using Tigase and not ejabberd?